# R - Swapping multiple columns in Large Matrix with predetermined distance in between

Tags: r, matrix

I need to swap multiple columns, and later rows, in a matrix that are a predetermined distance apart. For example, say I have a 9x9 matrix. I need to be able to swap cols 1 and 2, 4 and 5, and 7 and 8, simultaneously. 
I am looking for away to do this without using the `concatenate` function. Also, need the method to be valid for a I x J sized matrix.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to automate this procedure.

Comment: What language/environment are you using? Edit the post's tags with your answer.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: Do you know how to swap a single column? For instance, https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tips-swapping-columns-in-a-matrix/. Do you know how to use a loop to swap multiple columns?

Comment: I do, the problem is this is a piece of a much larger problem. All the examples of columns swapping I can find utilize the `concatenate` function. This won't be an acceptable way to conduct the swapping if the size of the matrix increases to 10,000 x 10,000. Unless there is a way to manipulate the `concat` function to handle unknown parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can just swap the needed columns with `[`-indexing

```
M <- matrix(1:81,9,9)
Mswapped <- M[ , c(2,1,3,5,4,6,8,79) ]
Mswapped
```

Not completely sure what you are referring to by "a predetermined distance apart". If you wanted to do the right-left-stable sequence as illustrated above, but programmatically, then create a "swap-vector" (1 for shift right, -1 for shift left, 0 for stay the same) and add to a sequence, thereby depending on R's recycling feature:

```
M[ , 1:dim(M)[2] + c(1,-1,0)]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]   10    1   19   37   28   46   64   55   73
 [2,]   11    2   20   38   29   47   65   56   74
 [3,]   12    3   21   39   30   48   66   57   75
 [4,]   13    4   22   40   31   49   67   58   76
 [5,]   14    5   23   41   32   50   68   59   77
 [6,]   15    6   24   42   33   51   69   60   78
 [7,]   16    7   25   43   34   52   70   61   79
 [8,]   17    8   26   44   35   53   71   62   80
 [9,]   18    9   27   45   36   54   72   63   81
```